# How to view a bitcoin cash transaction in hex or json?

Tags: bitcoin-cash, blockexplorer

Is there a block explorer that allows you to view a bitcoin cash transaction in hex or json like blockchain.info does for bitcoin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DoubleSpend.Cash](https://doublespend.cash/) can be used!

`https://doublespend.cash/txdata/9dbfbc12caa531afcfe00d90d786bd42cee2ef43.json`

UPDATE: Doublespend.cash works a little different. Here's a better alternative:

```
https://bch.blockdozer.com/api/tx/e6ed64fc714f4ffdd11b439ab1a22e1414bace2c05f38fa0221a58e45b678f74
```

Replace `/tx/` with `/rawtx/` to see the TX in the hex format.